# PHP How to display "Text Empty" if all files in directory are empty?

Tags: arrays, foreach, dir

Assume in my directory "my_dir/" contains files below:

```
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php
...
```

And assume each files is not empty..

```
<div id="file_data">
<?php $my_dir = glob("my_dir/*.php"); ?>  

<!-- This will display all files -->
<?php foreach($my_dir as $file) { ?>
<?php include $file; ?><br>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

If all or some file is not empty it will display some information in my page, but how to display custom text if all files are empty? I don't want in my page display no data/information.

Thanks for help, I am very beginner in programmer =)

Comment: if you want to display the files content, dont use include, it will execute the code, just use echo file_get_contents($file);

Comment: @Sirac I created that files to build an html element, all files are designed, so it's more simple for me if use include.. and I protect that files from direct access via .htacess, so anyone can not open it and file_get_contents method will not works properly too..

Comment: in my opinion file_get_contents should work, because it does not use a http-stream, and a .htaccess file has no influence here. you can set a return $somevalue at the end of your included files. include will return the value returned in your included file, so if the file is empty, nothing is returned and you can check your program by checking the return values of your include-statements

Comment: I am editing opencart CMS, you can try to get contents from my site: `file_get_contents('http://member.open-member.com/catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/download.tpl');` It will display `access denied` :D

Comment: this is true, but if you use file_get_contents with a relative filesystem-like path, a .htaccess does not prevent your file from being read. if you use file_get_contents with URL, it will process a http-request (where the .htaccess blocks the access), but if you use a filename, functions similar to fopen, fread, fclose etc. are used.

Answer (score 0):

To check the files for content, you can just add

```
return "finished"; //or some other return value
```

to the end of your files and use this code:

```
<div id="file_data">
<?php $my_dir = glob("my_dir/*.php");

$content = false; //no content echoed until now
foreach($my_dir as $file) {
    $returnValue = include($file);
    if ($returnValue == "finished"){ //or some other return-value to check
        //some content was successfull echoed
        $content = true;
        echo "<br>\n";
    }
}
if (!$content){
    echo "No content here"; //or just echo something more useful
} ?>
```

By the way, loading your content from several files and just loading all files in that directory is no good programming practice. an attacker could insert his files in your directory and insert its own code. also, it a put an non-php-file in your directory (aware of it or just an accident), include will result in an error and your page will not be created. i would try to think of another way to create your site in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't understand how your code works, it still display file's content and custom text "No content here" i can resolve it by creating a file and then check thats file (empty or not).. maybe there are better way to do that.. I am sorry if my english is bad :D

Comment: you dont have to apologize for bad english, my englsih skills arent that good too. Unfortunately i couldnt exactly understand, which part of the code i should explain. from your comment i understood that the code still echoes "No content here", even if files are included. if thats the case, then add "return somevaluehere" to your code and and change the first if-statement in the code above to "if ($returnValue == somevaluehere){". it might also work with "if ($returnValue){". its important to add an return-statement at the end of the file or the program wont notice. i hope i could help you.